# Use of affirmative do/does for emphasis

Tags: grammar

In a conversation, someone stated that regarding agile projects organization, "Creating different projects will not bring any benefits". I'm trying to disagree by saying something like:

> Different projects *does* enforce some rules ...

I want to indeed emphasize the verb "enforce", but I don't know if I should use "do" instead, like:

> Different projects *do* enforce some rules ...

Which one is correct? How do I determine the conjugation of "do"?

Comment: Without context, this is a bad question. *Unless* preceding context specifically includes ***someone else*** asserting that different projects ***don't*** enforce ***any*** rules, the cited text is unlikely to be idiomatically valid (this cited use of ***do*** normally only occurs when refuting an assertion to the contrary).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, but as a member of other stack communities I have to say a suggestion would be better than a down vote, specially because you have to consider that as an "english learners" community is probably difficult to users like me to give a great context in the questions.

Comment: Worth noting as well that this extends to situations where a statement might be unexpected in general (including if you had held some primary alternative expectation):
Scenario:
Sally starts her day thinking all projects were the same, and that they never enforced any rules.
She encounters a project that enforces some rules.
At that point, she could say "Wow, certain projects **_do_** enforce some rules"

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed.   It's identical to hundreds or thousands of other completely valid questions here, with a complete sentence prompt, and a question about use in a complete sentence reply.  Two alternatives are offered by OP, one is clearly correct use and the other is clearly incorrect use.   I can't imagine that the voter or voters here had legitimate intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Different projects *do* enforce some rules".

You are correct that you include `do` for emphasis and leave it out for typical usage here. "... projects does ..." is categorically wrong from a subject-verb agreement standpoint.

When talking about singular objects, you say

- <singular object> `(The project)` <third-person singular/"it" conjugation> `does` <bare form/dictionary form> `enforce`.
- <plural object> `(The projects)` <third-person plural/"they" conjugation> `do` <bare form/dictionary form> `enforce`.

This is because `do` belongs to a class of verbs called *helping verbs*, or *auxiliary verbs*. [This article from Lawless English](https://www.lawlessenglish.com/learn-english/grammar/auxiliary-verbs/) goes more into detail about this, but the verbs `do`, `be`, `have`, `will`, `may`, `can`, `shall` and `must` all *modify* the verb coming after them.

These are broadly lumped into two groups: `do`, `be`, and `have`; and the remaining verbs, which are called *modal verbs* for reasons not important to this question. These helping verbs are what get conjugated due to the subject noun. Thankfully, the verbs `do`, `be`, and `have` are the only verbs that have multiple forms; the rest (the modal verbs) only exist in one form.

The form of the verb after the helping verb depends only on which helping verb you're using- I `do *enforce*`, `am *enforcing*`, I `have *enforced*`; I `will/may/can/shall/must *enforce*`. You'll notice that `be` and `will/may/can/shall/must` all use `enforce`: these verbs use what's called the *bare form* or *bare infinitive*, which you can think of as just the plain, unconjugated form of the verb (what you use with "to <verb>"). This effectively means that you only need to think about `am` and `have` in this regard.

Example conjugations are as follows:

- I do <bare form>, she/he/it/<singular n.> does <bare form>, you/we/they/<plural> do <bare form>

  - Example: I do eat, she/he/it/the cat does eat, you/we/they/the cats do eat
  - Example: I do enforce, she/he/it/the project does enforce, you/we/they/the projects do enforce
- I have <past participle>, she/he/it/<singular n.> has <past participle>, you/we/they/<plural n.> have <past participle>

  - I have eaten, she/he/it/the cat has eaten, you/we/they/the cats have eaten
  - I have enforced, she/he/it/the project has enforced, you/we/they/the projects have enforced
- I am <present participle>, she/he/it/<singular n.> is <present participle>, you/we/they/<plural n.> are  <present participle>)

  - I am eating, she/she/it/the cat is eating, you/we/they/the cats are eating
  - I am enforcing, she/he/it/the project is enforcing, you/we/they/the cats are enforcing

See [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do#English#:~:text=Conjugation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do#English#:%7E:text=Conjugation) for conjugation rules for the verb `to do` (hit enter in the search bar after following the link on Chrome/Edge).

Comment: Why not be simple and say "does" is for singular words?

Comment: @Vanderlei Morais I updated the answer a bit to elaborate on the reasons. I hope this is more clear than my previous answer (and addresses any concerns)

Comment: @D.McKnight yes, perfectly clear, thank you it helped me a lot and I'm sure will help others too.